# Talent - Company page shows "Connection is Not Secure" error due to the http:// image

Tags: bug, status-completed, ssl, stack-overflow-talent

In the Stack Overflow Talent - Company page, if you didn't set any Cover Photo, by default it has [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpYbv.png) as a cover photo. Due to the `http://` image, the Company page shows a**Connection is Not Secure** error.

> [image: Not secure error]

As seen in this snippet, the image file is hard-coded in the inline styling:

```
<a href="/company/create-page">
    <div class="-cover" style="background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpYbv.png')"></div>
</a>
```

Can this be updated with `https://`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We're been running with HSTS enabled on `talent.stackoverflow.com` for a little over a year now and have been monitoring `Content-Security-Policy` reports to make sure this is a rare to non-existent occurrence. I'm *fairly certain* we've got all the major culprits of mixed content so I'm marking this as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)!

Thanks for the report <3